# When will Shopify include customer webhooks?

Tags: shopify, webhooks

Does anyone have any idea when/if Shopify will offer 'customers/created', 'customers/updated', and 'customers/delete' webhook events?

It would be great to be able to have our app notified when merchants are making changes to their customer records via their Store admin, or when someone creates a customer account without having completed an order.

Comment: I think we asked for this in the old Google Group... and it was acknowledged... and now we wait... I want this too!! I am jumping through all kinds of silly hoops connecting Apps to Customers...

Answer (score 0):

They now exist! Check them out at http://api.shopify.com/webhook.html